# Compare length of iterator with as few `next` calls as possible. How can I deduplicate this code?

Tags: python, iterator

I'm writing a few simple functions that compare the length of an iterator to an integer, returning as early as possible. Right now I have:

```py
class ILengthComparator:
    def __init__(self, iterator: Iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator

    def has_more(self) -> bool:
        try:
            next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            return False

        return True

    def __eq__(self, length: int) -> bool:
        if length < 0:
            return False

        if not self.has_more():
            return length == 0

        return self == length-1

    def __gt__(self, length: int) -> bool:
        if length < 1:
            return False

        if not self.has_more():
            return True

        return self > length-1

    def __lt__(self, length: int) -> bool:
        if length < 0:
            return True

        if not self.has_more():
            return False

        return self < length - 1
```

Clearly this class isn't finished (`__neq__`, `__gte__`, `__lte__`), and anything after the first comparison isn't guaranteed to work (as the iterator may be consumed), but I'm wondering: **is it is possible to logically simplify this** into a single function with an operator function as an argument (ie `operator.eq`, `operator.lt`), or at least just reduce the semi-duplicate parts (ie, every function has a comparison with `length` against a number, and a case for checking if the iterator is empty - each with a rather ad-hoc return value).

(any suggestions don't need to be recursive or use the `has_more` method, those were just the first thing I reached for when trying to solve this problem)

Pastebin with the above some quick and dirty unit tests: https://pastebin.com/N65Q2qcJ

Comment: (Would you believe in [total ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)?

Comment: @greybeard I could be wrong, but I don't think that would work, because  these methods have the side effect of consuming the iterator. So if the implementation requires combining `__eq__` and `__lt__` to determine `__gt__`, by the time `__lt__` was called, `__eq__` would have already consumed the iterator.

Comment: (For handling *consuming*, see [409_conflict's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235555/93149).)

Comment: As I understand it, `.tee()` often isn't a good idea, because it has to store the results of each `next()` call for _re_iteration (which can consume a decent amount of memory depending on what the iterator is iterating over). Even if not for this specific use case, it still seems like a pretty awesome decorator!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know the answer to your comparison to \$N\$, you need to attempt at least:

- \$N\$ `next` calls if you test with \$\lt\$ (succeeding will result to `False`) or \$\ge\$ (succeeding will result to `True`);
- \$N+1\$ `next` calls in all 4 other cases.

Obviously, if the iterator length is fewer than \$N\$ there will be less calls.

So, in order to simplify things, you could extract the first \$N+1\$ elements of the iterator and count them to compare this count to \$N\$:

- extracting can be simplified with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)
- counting can be done using either

  - `enumerate` and dumping the content into a 1-length [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

    ```
    from itertools import islice
    from collections import deque


    def compare_length(iterable, n, operation):
        chunck = islice(iterable, max(0, n+1))
        try:
            (length, _) = deque(enumerate(chunk, 1), maxlen=1)
        except ValueError:
            length = 0
        return operation(length, n)
    ```
  - `sum`

    ```
    from itertools import islice


    def compare_length(iterable, n, operation):
        chunck = islice(iterable, max(0, n+1))
        length = sum(1 for _ in chunck)
        return operation(length, n)
    ```

The former should be more efficient, the latter more readable. As suggested in the question, this function takes the operation to perform as its third argument and compares `min(<iterable length>, n+1)` to `n`. This is sufficient in most cases.

---

If you truly want to reduce the amount of `next` calls needed for \$\lt\$ and \$\ge\$, you can keep your class approach and factorize the `min(<iterable length>, n)` part into an helper method:

```
from itertools import islice


class ILengthComparator:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = iterable

    def _length_up_to(self, n):
        return sum(1 for _ in islice(self._iterable, max(0, n)))

    def __eq__(self, n):
        return self._length_up_to(n+1) == n

    def __ne__(self, n):
        return self._length_up_to(n+1) != n

    def __lt__(self, n):
        return self._length_up_to(n) < n

    def __le__(self, n):
        return self._length_up_to(n+1) <= n

    def __gt__(self, n):
        return self._length_up_to(n+1) > n

    def __ge__(self, n):
        return self._length_up_to(n) >= n
```

---

Lastly, if you want to avoid consuming the iterator while performing those tests, you can check [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).